# React Router re-render same component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**Problem:**

Have async route that get param `movie` from it and return `Movie Container` (component). The problem is when I go from one `MovieContainer` to another `MovieContainer` (just same route, but with diff. params) my router unmount and re-render `MovieContainer` component. But it should just pass new props and don't touch my component lifesycle. How to solve it ? What I do wrong ?

**Code:**

Router

```
<Route path="/" component={AppLayout}>
  <IndexRoute components={{ children: Home }} />
  <Route path=":movie/about" getComponents={(nextState, callback) => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    const movie = findMovie(nextState.params.movie);
    return callback(null, { children: (router) => <Movie movie={movie} router={router} /> });
  }}/>
  ....
</Route>
```

Component WillMount in Movie component

```
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('MOUNT MovieContainer');
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
OK, Done some experiment.

Replace

`return callback(null, { children: (router) => <Movie movie={movie} router={router} /> });`

With

`return callback(null, Movie);`

Andd `Movie component` not re-renderd. Just updated. It's great! But how to pass props now ?

Comment: This is correct and desired behavior. New routes should re-mount all components.

Comment: @AndyRay but it's not new route, just `/movie1/about` to `/movie2/about`

This route pattern `/:someparams` created only for passing new props to the same component. So, why it should re-render ?

Comment: That is absolutely a new route.

Comment: @AndyRay ok, for example I have an app where I watch movies and have side bar that changes when my router changes like `/movie/menu` `/movie/actors`. And you try to tell me that it's OK that my movie will be re-renered every time when I just change my sidebar ?

Answer (score 1):

Great! Finally I found solution.

```
<Route path=":movie/about" getComponents={(nextState, callback) => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  callback(null, Movie);
}}
/>
```

And in component I can access props via `this.props.params.movie` than find movie in constructor/componentWillMount `const movie = findMovie(nextState.params.movie);`